# Missing solutions for the ODE $y' + 5y = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Let's solve the ODE  $y' + 5y = 0$ through separation of variables.

We get

\begin{align*}
\frac 1y y' &= -5 \\
\log|y| &= -5x+c \\
|y| &= \exp(-5x+c) \\
y &= \pm \exp(-5x+c) \\
&= \pm \exp(c)\exp(-5x) \\
&=  \pm c_1 \exp(-5x), c_1 > 0
\end{align*}

How come the solution where $c_1 = 0$ is missing?

Comment: You divided by $y$, which doesn’t work if $y=0$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Oh of course! Thanks. Is there a general way to solve these that won't require me to check restricted solutions afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you solve an equation by separation of variables
$$
y'=f(x)g(y)
$$
you could have some singular solutions (solutions that don't show up in the general integral) by taking a constant solution $y=y_0.$ If you substitute, you get
$$
0=f(x)g(y_0)
$$
from which you can conclude that every zero of $g$ is a constant solution.

Answer (score 1):

*Is there a general way to solve these that won't require me to check restricted solutions afterwards*

Yes integrating factor method is easier here:
$$y'+5y=0$$
$$(ye^{5x})'=0$$
$$ye^{5x}=C$$
$$y=Ce^{-5x}$$